# Regular Expression for full Linux File Path

Tags: python, regex, linux

I am trying to create a regular expression to find Linux file paths within text however regex is very new to me. I have the snippet below that will identify the beginning of the file structures below.

```
.*(/bin/|/home/).*
```

What would be the best way to complete the regex to get any possible sub-directories and files after "/bin/" or "/home/"?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since paths can contain spaces, are you wanting to handle that case or only support the case for paths without spaces? Admittedly spaces are somewhat rare in linux, but they are perfectly valid. Also, paths can begin with ".", "..". And, of course, paths can begin with just about anything (eg: "foo/bar", "$HOME/.virtualenvs", etc. Do you care about all of those cases, or only about paths that begin with "/" and have no spaces?

Comment: Ideally I would want the regex to handle the potential spaces. I will only care about paths that begin with "/" and "~/". I though initially I could have (/bin/|/home/|/sbin|/etc|/root|/lib|/dev|/tmp|/boot|/mnt/proc|/usr|/var) within the regex (with any other folders in the root file system) to do this, not sure if that is the best way do that or not?

Answer (score 0):

Though your RegEx does technically select all sub-directories and files, try this RegEx:

```
.*(/bin/|/home/)(\w+(?:\.\w+)+|(\w+/))+
```

Each folder of file will be stored in a different group

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/xS3yY9/1)</kbd>

---

How it works:

```
.*(/bin/|/home/)          # Select /bin/ or /home/
(                         # Capture each sub-directory or file
   \w+(?:\.\w+)+              # File name (with extension(s))
   |                          # OR
   (\w+/)                     # Final Folder Name
)+                        # Capture each one or more times
```